# Use <BalloonStyle> without creating empty balloons

Tags: kml, style, google-earth

In attempting to find at least a partial solution for [Google Earth font change](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/226102/71380), changing the font for my own placemark balloons, I ran into another problem.

If I use `<BalloonStyle>` to give styling for balloons then every placemark affected by this style is given a balloon whether or not there is any `$[description]` text.  Normally the balloon is suppressed if the description is empty.

For example I may wish to use:

```
<BalloonStyle>
  <text>
    <font size="+2">$[description]</font>
  </text>
</BalloonStyle>
```

However if I use this style for a placemark without a description I get an empty balloon.

[image]

Can I give styling using `<BalloonStyle>` and still have suppression of balloons for empty descriptions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't put balloon styling/formatting into the `<BalloonStyle>` and still have it suppress balloons for features with empty descriptions.

A feature (Placemark, etc.) will have a balloon if it has any content or HTML in either its description tag OR in the `<BalloonStyle><text>` tag in its Styles section. In your example, it's the `<font>` tags in your BalloonStyle which are causing the balloon to be enabled.

If you want to suppress the balloons based on whether or not your description tag is empty, then you will need to remove everything except the description variable from the BalloonStyle/text tag, like this:

```
<BalloonStyle>
  <text>$[description]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
```

Of course that diminishes the usefulness of a shared BalloonStyle, since you can't put your HTML structure and formatting in there, but have to include it in each description instead.

Another approach might be to have a second shared Style, with no BalloonStyle, and apply that to the features where you don't want balloons.